# CKEditor 5 and Vite 5: TypeError: __require.resolve is not a function

Tags: vite, ckeditor5

I'm trying to upgrade from Vite 4 to Vite 5.

After updating to Vite 5, I got the following warning:

```
The CJS build of Vite's Node API is deprecated. See https://vitejs.dev/guide/troubleshooting.html#vite-cjs-node-api-deprecated for more details.
```

So I edited `package.json` and added `"type": "module",`.

Then I tried to build the app again and got the following error:

```
 ERROR  failed to load config from /Users/private/d/ionic/vite.config.ts                                                                                                   21:33:20


 ERROR  error during build:                                                                                                                                                21:33:20
TypeError: __require.resolve is not a function
    at vite_config_default (file:///Users/private/d/ionic/vite.config.ts.timestamp-1700829200243-c26807f7c170c.mjs:80:36)
    at loadConfigFromFile (file:///Users/private/d/ionic/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-ErEj4WmL.js:66149:15)
    at async resolveConfig (file:///Users/private/d/ionic/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-ErEj4WmL.js:65750:28)
    at async build (file:///Users/private/d/ionic/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-ErEj4WmL.js:64922:20)
    at async CAC.<anonymous> (file:///Users/private/d/ionic/node_modules/vite/dist/node/cli.js:845:9)
```

This is caused by the way I am importing the CKEditor 5 plugin.  I know this because when I remove the CKEditor 5 plugin from my `vite.config.ts`, the error does not appear. (Of course, in that case, the app doesn't work, because CKEditor doesn't get imported properly.)

I think this is because CKEditor is using CJS, but Vite is now defaulting to ESM.  There is [work underway to have CKEditor default to ESM](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5/issues/13673), but the PRs have not been committed yet. So how do I use CKEditor with Vite 5 in ESM mode today?

Comment: I just created a fresh Vite 5 project with CKEditor5 following the official tutorial in the CKEditor documentation and it works fine. Please make sure you don't use `require.resolve` directly, but use the `createRequire( import.meta.url )` method as shown here: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/installation/advanced/alternative-setups/integrating-from-source-vite.html#vite-configuration. If this doesn't help, please share your `vite.config.js` file.

Comment: @FilipSobol Thanks, I needed to use `require.resolve` as you described.  Feel free to add that as an answer and I will accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure to not use `require.resolve` directly, but use the `createRequire( import.meta.url )` method as shown in the CKeditor documentation: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/installation/advanced/alternative-setups/integrating-from-source-vite.html#vite-configuration